# Why System.Drawing.Rectangle allow contain negative sizes (width, height)?

Tags: c#, rectangles, system.drawing

I understand that Rectangle (and RectangleF) ctor allows negative sizes, but I don't understand why the ctor doesn't translates that in the "real values" that must have the rectangle, for example:

```
x:0, y:0, w:-100, h:200 == x:-100, y:0, w:100, h:200
```

And so on. It doesn't make sense. If you ask for area in the first case (W x H) you get... negative area. If you ask for perimeter then it's totally broken. It forces you to write a lot of boilerplate `Math.Abs` when the logic and maths (basic maths) says "The sizes of a shape can not be negative".

And if you use `FromLTRB` then you have to start to make min's and max's and it's a lot of dirty code.

Is there any subtle reason why the .net team made the Rectangle ctor in this way?

And, in the end, is there any included method to build rectangles "in the right way" or do i have to do one?

Edit: I found another problem, I'll call it a bug; if you use negative x (e.g:-100) and a negative width (e.g:-200) it says "my right is -300". And the same with Top & Bottom & Left. ¡Nice! 
I can understand the way he treats the negatives sizes, but this seems unacceptable to me. Now the right isn't the right...

Comment: Different use cases may have different policy. For example, you might have a rectangle that represents a portion of the screen, and you shrink the rectangle based on the things that are going into that space. If you have too much stuff, the rectangle's width goes negative, say to `-100` as you showed above. Does this really mean that there's room for 100 pixels of content? No, it means that you ran out of space, and the width should be treated as zero. Also, the width may go negative but only temporarily. For example, subtracting 50 pixels then adding 50 pixels should be a nop.

Comment: Rectangles (and other structures) are not used just for drawing. They can be used in any kind of calculations. It's like wondering why there are negative numbers since you can't spend -10 dollars so *something* should make then positive for your convenience.

Comment: @Jimi I understand that, but, if i ask the rectangle "hey, what is your width?" I expect (IMHO) a "possible" value, a positive one: the width is 100, different thing is that the direction is "to the left". But ok, I understand it, I've built one static function to fulfill my requirements.

Comment: @Jimi What do you think about my edit, do you think that it's ok?

Comment: The right at -300 is the right if the rectangle is mirrored. This doesn’t make much difference in the case of a simple rectangle shape as it will look the same whether you draw it this way or that,, but consider a rectangular image of a car, the right way round (license plate readable). Now the user grabs the right hand handle and drags the right side of the rectangle through the origin and out the other side to -300. The right is still the right but it’s now visually on the left (the right hand side of the car is still the right) and the license plate is backwards.

Comment: Here we are not talking about any image or control, we are talking about the abstraction "Rectangle", and independently of the negativity of the values, the right is the right, aka the greater X value. and the bottom is the bottom, aka the greater Y value. The rectangle shouldn't understand if it's mirrored or not (obviously it acts like it does).

Comment: You're considering just one possible coordinates system and only a single *direction* inside those coordinates, where anything starts from the top/left side and ends in the bottom/right side, GDI World-wise. See [this quite basic example](https://imgur.com/a/Vf3YKUp) using the same coordinates system, considering that is not the only one and that no transformations are applied. Now consider a what happens to the Rectangle dimension when multiple Matrix transformations are in place. Can you handle negative values? Because you should.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, I understand that the values must allow negatives because the transformations, but that doesn't allow change the concept of "the right": the right of the orange rectangle in your gif should be the right (max X) side, not the left side.

Comment: `Left` and `Right` are relative concepts.  Ask a mirror :) If the coordinates system is rotated, where's the Right side (the position of your hands is of no consequence to your evaluation here)?

Comment: "Ask a mirror". The problem here is the screen (i think) isn't a mirror. Inherently has a right an a left. And a rectangle (a struct inside the "Drawing" namespace, but it doesn't matter) can have negative values, but the right is in our right when we write software (obviously we -normally- use standard basis), even if the values of the width or height are negatives. I understand it's a semantics problem and not a "software" problem.

Comment: Yes, it's not about how we write (whom? I write from left to right. Do you? I know people that don't, so, given the point of origin, the left side could be considered negative). The plane/world coordinates can be rotated/translated/flipped/mirrored. Lose the human concept of `left` and `right`. Unless it's something you want to point to with a finger.

Answer (score 0):

To me a rectangle with negative sizes would simply be one that extended left and up from its origin point rather than right and down in classic drawing? There aren’t any restrictions on it though because it’s just a pairing of 4 numbers, and there isn’t a restriction on whether a number can be negative or not- a negative width might mean something to your app

You don’t need to do lots of complicated Math all throughout your code though; just decide how you want to handle negative values and create a wrapper class around a rectangle struct that implements the rules. If you decide that width shall not be negative, wrap your rectangle, make a property or constructor that just performs Abs on the width when you set it and away you go. Any time you want a rectangle to draw, get it out of your wrapper

```
class Rectitive{
  private Rectangle r;
  public Rectangle R { get{return r}; private set; }

  public int Width { get { return r.Width } set { r.Width = math.Abs(value); } }

  public Rectitive(int x, int y, int w, int h){
    r = new Rectangle(Math.Abs(x) ...);
  }


}



e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myRectitive.R);
```

Do note that these are business rules you define yourself. If I were writing this system that deals with negative size rectangles I would turn a rectangle at location 50,70 of size -100,-200 into a rectangle at -50,-130 of size 100,200

Comment: The last part of the answer it's the only thing that makes sense in all of this i think. If one rectangle has negative sizes there is one exactly equal rectangle with all sizes positive (swaps start point with top-left). Then, why use negative sizes? is it so important tell "hey, this rectangle is going up and left from origin"? I'm going to make a static method for building. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it’s more a consequence of how the rectangle is generated. You might have a shape the user has dragged out in a up/left direction or resized by moving from the existing bottom right all the way through the origin and into a new top left. You might even choose to keep the sizes negative to indicate that a flip/mirror has occurred on something that has an orientation, like an image - it might even be how your user flips things - they want the image upside down, grab the bottom handle and drag it all the way down to 0 height then keep going so the image has -100 height